# Images as pagination links in cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have a gallery custom coded using cakePHP. Currently, I'm trying to get the pagination links for next and previous page to appear as images. The links work perfectly as text. In order to output them as simple text, I use the following code:

```
<?php   
echo $this->Paginator->prev();
echo $this->Paginator->next();      
?>
```

However, this outputs the links as text saying `<< Previous` and `Next >>` respectively. I want to replace said output for images I have. I have looked around and found something that replaces the text for the image:

```
echo $this->paginator->prev($this->html->image('/images/icon_prev.png'), array('escape' => false));
```

However, it seems to break the link: While the link for the standard previous/next buttons go as:

```
http://galleryurlhere/albums/view/7/page:2
```

The new image link outputs them as:

```
http://galleryurlhere/albums/view/page:2
```

Thus failing to send the album ID as a variable and therefore breaking the pagination. Can anyone help me with this? I've tried overloading the function with the variable (Which I can access from the code), but that doesn't seem to be working. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exact version are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not make much sense but the problem is in how you call the Helper.

This does NOT work properly

```php
echo $this->paginator->prev( $this->html->image('/images/icon_prev.png'), array('escape' => false) );
```

while this DOES:  (note the capital "***P***")

```php
echo $this->Paginator->prev( $this->html->image('/images/icon_prev.png'), array('escape' => false) );
```

**More details**

It seems like `$this->Paginator` is *not* the same object as `$this->paginator` (spl_object_hash()). Similarly I would use `$this->Html` and not `$this->html` as my Html Helper.

Comment: This has to be the single most stupid reason why I've ever gotten stuck on a project. Also, the main thing I hate from cakePHP is precisely how it happily uses capitalization and plurals for classes and objects deliberately, lending itself to confusion. I've tested your suggestion and, indeed, it worked. Kudos to you, sir!